# How can I see request and network profiling on an app that is decompiled by Android studio?

Tags: apk, profiles

I chose "Profile or Debug APK" in Android Studio and chose a downloaded apk. Then, when I try to profile it, I see spikes in network tab, but I cannot see network requests and responses.

1. Any solution for this?
2. Does downloading apk from websites matters?

Comment: I believe [it's only possible on debuggable apps](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/apk-debugger). APKs from the internet are usually taken from the Play Store, and those have their debuggable flag set to false. Otherwise, [they get prevented from being published](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32263949/you-uploaded-a-debuggable-apk-for-security-reasons-you-need-to-disable-debuggin).

Comment: @AndrewT. - Thanks for answering. So, if apps can't be released unless debuggable = false, then when Android studio has an option "debug pre-built apks" while opening android studio is counter statement. Which means, we can profile only the apps that we develop. Is that correct?

Comment: @sofs1 That is the purpose of Android Studio. But you can use apktool to decompile the app, change debuggable flag and recompile and sign it. Some apps my check for debuggable flag and signature and refuse to run but a lot will just run.